# Selective Numpy array manipulation (dependent on value)

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have the following Numpy array:

```
array([[3, 5, 0], [7, 0, 2]])
```

I now want to add 2 where the value is not 0. What would be the fastest way to do this? I have to manipulate quite large multidimensional arrays?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me that:

```
a[a!=0] += 2
```

should work.

(for the limited case of testing for non-zero-ness), you *might* be able to speed things up with (you'd need to `timeit` to see):

```
mask = a.astype(bool)
a[mask] += 2
```

---

Of course, you can save yourself the mask calculation *if* you can reuse the same mask at different spots (which is a pretty restrictive constraint):

```
mask = a != 0
a[mask] += 2
#some more code ...
a[mask] *= 3
#more code ...
```

---

Of course, If this is enough of a bottleneck, you can always write a little C/Fortran extension to do this for you (using `Cython` or `f2py` respectively).  This would avoid the overhead of mask creation.

Comment: Reusing the mask is a good idea, however it may not reflect the current state (imagine there is a `-2` in the array and you want to add 2 twice).

Comment: @eumiro -- Yeah. the *if you can reuse the same mask* is a pretty restrictive constraint.

Comment: @mgilson -- that's interesting as numpy behaves here differently than I used to. "a[a!=0] += 2" does not give the same result as "a = a[a!=0] + 2".

Comment: @Zardoz of course it doesn't, the first case changes `a` in-place, the second creates a new array (which is smaller). You might be able to get a bit more speed with `np.putmask` if you really want.

Comment: Cool! in 1.7 you could do `np.add(a, 2, where=mask)` too, to save a bit... but its all small optimzations anways

Comment: @seberg -- of course, but the interesting point for me is that the structure of the array is completely different in both results: "a[a!=0] + 2" instead returns a one dimensional array. I just want to emphasize this for other Numpy newbies.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the size of your array but you could consider using [numexpr](http://code.google.com/p/numexpr/) for this:

```
# from your exemmple
>>> a = array([[3, 5, 0], [7, 0, 2]])
>>> %timeit a[a!=0] += 2
100000 loops, best of 3: 18.6 us per loop
>>> timeit numexpr.evaluate("a + 2 * (a != 0)")
10000 loops, best of 3: 42.6 us per loop
```

But with a bigger array:

```
# make a big array with 10% of zeros :
a = np.random.rand(10000)
a[a<0.1] = 0
# same test:
>>> timeit a[a!=0] += 2
1000 loops, best of 3: 364 us per loop
>>> timeit numexpr.evaluate("a + 2 * (a != 0)")
10000 loops, best of 3: 119 us per loop
```

And this is with a single core. Numepxr makes use of all core available if possible.